# @Field annotations attributes not working for dynamic mapping feature

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are running spring-data 4.1.0, Spring 5.2.10

This may sound weird but here is the scenario (state of es No index/mapping):

Fire up the container and the first thing `spring-data-es` does is create the index with all the mapping. yea! but if that process fails for some reason the mapping does not get created. ok understandable.

After that(mapping failed) you save an entity.. it appears spring/es will dynamically start generating the mapping for that entity as it is getting saved. Cool.. yea! but... some of the @Field attributes are not getting into the mapping. IE copy_to attribute.

I don't know how all the dynamic mapping works, if it is on the java side or the es side. I guess if the dynamic mapping is happening on the es side then this behavior makes sense. But i think i noticed other `@Field` attributes making its way into the mapping like the field type and data conversion stuff.

Is this the expected behavior? I guess i am thinking that `@Field` annotation attributes should make its way into the mapping regardless as to how the mapping gets created.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are correct.

The `@Field` annotations only are considered when the mapping is written with Spring Data Elasticsearch - on repository initialization or when one of the corresponding methods from the `IndexOperations` interface is called.

When the mapping on index creation fails it is not automatically done afterwards. And it will not be done on the next application start as the index then already exists.

When an entity is stored in an index that does not have a mapping defined, Elasticsearch automatically creates the mapping, and as Elasticsearch does not know anything about Spring Data Elasticsearch annotations.

Did you get an error in the application when the mapping could not be stored?

Comment: That is what I was sort of thinking. Yes I an error when the mapping could not be stored, but did not know until i verified on the es side. Once I fixed the mapping exceptions, the mapping is getting created properly.  I think when a mapping exception happens we need more text in the log so it stands out :) getting blind in my old age. :)...